# How to write and/or operator in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have to use AND/OR operators to hibernate detached criteria queries.

The SQL query is:

```
select *from tableName where col1='value1' and col2='value2' and (col3='value3' or col4='value3');
```

I think it's like this:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(tableName.class)
                            .add(Property.forName("col1").eq(value1))
                            .add(Property.forName("col2").eq(value2))
                            ....????????);
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Property.forName("col3").eq("value3"),
                             Property.forName("col4").eq("value3")));
```

is useful when you only have two expressions linked by an `or` (or an `and`, with `Restrictions.and`).

If you have more than two expressions, then use a disjunction or a conjunction:

```
Disjunction orExpression = Restrictions.disjunction();
orExpression.add(Property.forName("col3").eq("value3"))
            .add(Property.forName("col4").eq("value3"))
            .add(Property.forName("col5").eq("value3"));
criteria.add(orExpression);
```